# Username-Password OAuth Authentication is working with the community users?

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, connected-apps

I need to configure Username-Password OAuth Authentication to get salesforce data with the REST API through a community users. Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! We have done the same. Once the user is created we do a login using the SOAP login request and from then on use the sessiontoken for making REST API requests.

[Soap Login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_login.htm)

[Rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/)

Comment: I am trying to login a community user using Soap login from a native ios app but it says "unsupported_grant_type" also i found this link that says community user cannot use Username-Password Authentication https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_auth_configure_oauth.htm&type=0